# Detecting if the Back Button was pressed from previous activity

Tags: java, android, textview

So, (for example) let's say I have an activity with a method that sets the test of a TextView

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        setTextView();
    }
    public void setTextView() {
        String myText = ...//fetches text from web server
        tv.setText(myText);
    }
}
```

If I go to another activity from this one, and the back button is pressed and I return to this activity, I want to be able to recall my `setTextView()` method to update the text in the TextView. Is it possible to detect when a person "backs" into the activity? Thanks

Comment: Overide onBackpressed method may work.

Comment: @Nambari correct me if I'm wrong but onBackPressed is called from the activity you are pressing back on and not the one you are "backing" to

Comment: Yes, there pass the value as part of bundle and inside onResume of original activity get the value and populate it to the textview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case calling `setTextView` from `onResume` instead of `onCreate` is enough, since when you press back the current activity is finished and the previous one is resumed.

Comment: Ahh I tried using onResume but I was calling "setTextView" from onResume in addition to onCreate and was getting a bad result. Makes sense why I only needed it on onResume. Thanks, will accept this when I can